# AWS AMQP + SSL Connection with vertx

Tags: amazon-web-services, vert.x, activemq-artemis

I am trying to connect a service with activemQ in my local i am trying with this connection:

```
fun start(vertx: Vertx, address: String): Single<MQServerConnection> {
    val options: AmqpClientOptions = AmqpClientOptions()
        .setHost("localhost")
        .setPort(5672)
    logger.info("ACTIVE_MQ_PROVIDER_STARTING_IN_THREAD_[" + Thread.currentThread().name + "]")

    return AmqpClient.create(vertx, options).rxConnect().flatMap { amqpConnection ->
        amqpConnection.rxCreateAnonymousSender().flatMap { responseSender ->
            amqpConnection.rxCreateReceiver(address).map { receiver ->
                MQServerConnection(amqpConnection, responseSender, receiver)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where

```
data class MQServerConnection(
    val amqpConnection: AmqpConnection,
    val amqpSender: AmqpSender,
    val amqpReceiver: AmqpReceiver
)
```

And it works fine.

Now i am trying to use the AWS service, but it returns to me:

```
failover:(amqp+ssl://b-4eb4c78c-048b-436c-941e-31250830323e-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671,amqp+ssl://b-4eb4c78c-048b-436c-941e-31250830323e-2.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:5671)
```

I don't know how to send the HOST instead of localhost

and insted of port.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ssl property of AmqpClientOptions has to be true for AMQPS, i.e.

```
val options: AmqpClientOptions = AmqpClientOptions()
    .setHost("b-4eb4c78c-048b-436c-941e-31250830323e-1.mq.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
    .setPort(5671)
    .setSsl(true)
    .setUsername("admin")
    .setPassword("admin")
    //This is required only if the AWS service uses a self-signed certificate
    .setTrustAll(true)
    //This is required only if the AWS service uses a certificate with a CN that doesn't match the hostname
    .setHostnameVerificationAlgorithm("")
```

Comment: But is necessary from code manage the fail over? i need create in code some method to conect to the other host if the first host fail? or AWS do it or some library do it?

Comment: The Vert.x AMQP Client doesn't support failover, see this open issue https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-amqp-client/issues/33